# Is there a better alternative to web sockets for high-rate data transfer between server and web-client?

Tags: browser, websocket, server, real-time, transfer

The web-client goal is to display the data in real-time. We are aiming at a speed of 40 packets of 500 000 int32 per second.

Comment: Do you mean you need to deliver data at 40*500,000*4*8 = 640 Mbit/s? Any web browser would probably have some trouble processing them. In any case, the websocket itself does not have any issue with high-rate data transfer. So, you don't need to look for alternative protocols.

Comment: @AlessandroAlinone Yes 640 Mbits/s. What you're saying make sense! But would there be a way for the browser to handle all that data more efficiently? (e.g sending bigger packets but less frquently). And to be more realistic, let's say we shoot 320 Mbits/s.

Comment: It all depends on what the browser needs to do with the received data. Just throw them away (as speed tests do)? Append them to an HTML page? Parse them based on some syntax? Display them in some tabular or graphical format? By the way, bigger and less frequent packets will not probably make any difference.

Comment: @AlessandroAlinone the browser needs to render 4 webgl views! Each packet has a header which specifies to which view it belongs. Rendering is of course done with 4 requestAnimationFrame loops. We also handled scrolling on the client-side instead of sending all the data of the view at once.

Comment: Ok, did you test it? What issues did you find?

Comment: @AlessandroAlinone It works, but we got low fps... It's a bit better when using chrome canary or firefox developer, but even then, it's not very high...

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way to try getting the stream from the disk, rather than from the network. In that case, if you still get low fps, the culprit is the browser processing. Otherwise, you could delve into the network (websocket client, link, websocket server).